# Append "Teacher" to "Student" Profile

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, profile, user-profile

I have the following model setup:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('TeacherProfile', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

In my view, I want the teacher to append herself as the student's teacher in the studentprofile. This is what I have thus far:

```
def teach_student(request, student_id):
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, student_id=student_id)
    StudentProfile.objects.create(teacher=request.user.teacher, student=student)
    return redirect('account:path_to_students_without_teacher')
```

**PROBLEM:**

I'm getting an error on `StudentProfile.objects.create(teacher=request.user.teacher, student=student)`

```
Cannot assign "<StudentProfile: Student One (@student)>": "StudentProfile.student" must be a "User" instance.
```

**QUESTION:**

*Any suggestions on how to allow a teacher to append herself as the student's teacher?*

Answer (score 1):

In your data model, the field `student` on `StudentProfile` refers to a `User`. However, in your method, you seem to have a class called `Student`. You didn't specify where this class comes from, but it seems that that is what Django is complaining about: the variable `student` in the method is of type `Student` where it should be of type `User`.

Comment: On fetching from User rather than StudentProfile model in the view, I'm met with a "UNIQUE constraint failed error" any idea on resolution?

Comment: It depends a bit on the specific error, but my first guess is that you should replace `StudentProfile.objects.create` with `StudentProfile.objects.update_or_create`.

Answer (score 0):

your model class it's your problem, you create an `AbstractUser` class for your custom users fields but it only contains `is_student` and `is_teacher` you must set this in group model not to set these in you user model so you must have a user and the user related to one or many groups like admin, teacher, student, schoolmaster or ...

next you dont need `class StudentProfile(models.Model)` you must put that field in `AbstractUser` class so

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # set any field like phone_number or something except f-name, l-name, or anything that django create that by defult
```

anyway
you don't have any Student model in here you need to

```
def teach_student(request, student_id):
    student = get_object_or_404(User, student_id=student_id)
    StudentProfile.objects.create(teacher=request.user, student=student)
    return redirect('account:path_to_students_without_teacher')
```

it safest way is to check if this user is a teacher or not like and check for login

```
@login_required
def teach_student(request, student_id):
    teacher = User.object.get(id=request.user.id)
    if teacher.is_teacher:
        student = get_object_or_404(User, student_id=student_id)
        StudentProfile.objects.create(teacher=request.user, student=student)
        return redirect('account:path_to_students_without_teacher')
    else:
        return False # or redirect to another page and show an error
```

if you set group for users you can do more thing to set permission in your def